# Congratulations to the new moderators of 2011

Tags: discussion, announcements

**Congratulations to the [new moderators](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/1) William Huber ([whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664)), [Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/276/mapperz), and Anita Graser ([underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark)).**

Comment: I know first hand the kinds of work you will be doing and I thank you for taking on the role. I'm confident our community will benefit from your efforts. Be well and happy :)

Comment: Many thanks, hope to do as a good job as you did. Congratulations to whuber and underdark too. Hope we make a good team and keep up the great community of GISse.

Comment: Thanks for your commitments and existing contributions to the site! I'm glad we ended up with moderators who span the community nicely.

Comment: Thanks everyone for voting and congratulations to whuber and Mapperz.

Comment: Congrats... shocking side for me to see poor voting rates... less than 50% of eligible voters voted..(out of 250 only 96 voted).. This need additional consideration for moderator and community to look into future direction...

Comment: The comment about "poor voting rates" has been addressed at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448/why-did-the-2011-moderator-elections-not-represent-a-good-voting-rate.

Comment: Congratulations, and thanks from a new user. I've already benefited from whuber's and underdark's thoughtful and thorough responses to the small torrent of questions I've posted in the past few days. You all (this community) make it possible to learn a challenging new skill much faster than would otherwise be possible, not to mention a lot of fun. Cheers!

Comment: This "Question" is hanging around Unanswered and might be best Closed (but not deleted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applause is an appropriate answer.